# How to cycle through pages of a PDf using VBScript

Tags: pdf, vbscript, adobe

I am trying to write something in VBS that will cycle through an 8 page PDF document displaying each for a certain amount of time, before continuing on to a webpage. However, when I try to navigate to a different page of the PDF, the program does not do so, it just remains on the first opened PDF page for the entire time.

```
  Dim IE 
  Dim objShell 

  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
  IE.Visible = True 
  IE.FullScreen = True
  IE.StatusBar = False

  objShell.AppActivate"Windows Internet Explorer"


  IE.Navigate("\\full\path\file.pdf#page=1")
  WScript.Sleep(10000)

  IE.Navigate("\\full\path\file.pdf#page=2")
  WSCript.Sleep(10000)
  ...   
  IE.Navigate("\\full\path\file.pdf#page=8")
  WScript.Sleep(10000) 

  IE.Navigate("https:// webpage.url")
  IE.Quit
```

So my question is how do I fix this? How can I write a script such that it actually changes the PDF page displayed?

Comment: What makes you think `\\full\path\file.pdf#page=1` is an acceptable syntax?  It could be just ignoring your `#page=1`.

Comment: @rory.ap when i run just one line by itself and change the page number it opens on the page number specified

Answer (score 1):

The `page` parameter is usable only on file open. After the pdf document is already open, the command does not take the page parameter. One solution would be to close the pdf before opening it to the new page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Would there be anyway to change the page without having to close and re-open the file every single time?

Comment: I do not know of such possibility, using IE.